# BigQuery Authorized Views For External Connection

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Is there any way to treat a BigQuery "External Connection" like a BQ database for which views can be authorized?

I have a Cloud SQL DB that I'm accessing via an "external connection" in BigQuery. I have a BigQuery Dataset that contains a view that is essentially just `select * from external_db;` I'd like to keep access to that view and the external connection limited, but I'd like to make a second Dataset with a view such as `select field 1, field2 from view1(or external_db);` that I can give others read access to.

Comment: The best option I've come up with so far is creating a view in the SQL DB and adding a new user that only has read permission for that view. The external connection can then be created with that user and it is appropriately restricted. I don't hate this option.

Comment: Do you want to create Bigquery authorized view from the source DB view which is located in a separate dataset?

Comment: no, the source DB is located in an external database.

Comment: If you create the second view `select field 1, field2 from external_db` in the separate Bigquery dataset, assigning appropriate access control to the users, wouldn't it be sufficient here?

Comment: I dont think so. If I give a user permission to read that view it'll give an error indicating a lack of permissions on the external dataset and there's no way to give the user access to the external dataset without them being able to access the whole thing.

Comment: I believe that there is nothing that can be feasible to achieve on Bigquery side then, thus the appropriate security access has to be implemented on SQL DB side. Did you get the desired result this way?

Comment: Yeah, restricting access to the view in SQL is good enough. I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best option I've come up with so far is creating a view in the SQL DB and adding a new user that only has read permission for that view. The external connection can then be created with that user and it is appropriately restricted.